# Software Properties will not run

Tags: package-management, kubuntu, software-sources

I can't configure repositories and things on my Kubuntu 14.04 LTS system.

When I run kdesudo software-properties-kde it asks me for my password then gives this traceback message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-properties-kde", line 136, in <module> 
    app = SoftwarePropertiesKDE(datadir=data_dir, options=options, file=afile, attachWinID=attachWinID)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/kde/SoftwarePropertiesKDE.py", line 64, in __init__                                                                       
    SoftwareProperties.__init__(self, options=options, datadir=datadir) 
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 103, in __init__ 
    self.sourceslist = SourcesList()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/sourceslist.py", line 274, in __init__ 
    self.matcher = SourceEntryMatcher(matcherPath)                           
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/sourceslist.py", line 459, in __init__ 
    dist = DistInfo(f, base_dir=matcherPath)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/distinfo.py", line 186, in __init__ 
    for line in dist_file:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/codecs.py", line 313, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final) 
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xae in position 2: invalid start byte
```

I can't use add-apt-repository or software-properties-gtk either. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: What is the package versions of the python3-software-properties, software-properties-common and software-properties-kde ? At here: 0.92.37 (apt-cache policy software-properties-kde).

Comment: You could re-install the software-properties packages with the command: 'sudo apt-get install --reinstall <package>'

Comment: @user26687 I am using 0.92.37 and I have tried reinstalling the packages and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

My `/usr/share/python-apt/templates/Ubuntu.info` file was corrupt. I simply replaced it with a new copy and it was fine.

Thank You Everyone

Comment: If your Ubuntu.info file was corrupt, just do an `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-apt-common`

Comment: `/usr/share/python-apt/templates/Ubuntu.info` is provided by  *python-apt-common* from the default Ubuntu repositories.